# Combinatorial Probability Question Similar to Sheldon Ross's A First Course in Probability 10th ed Chapter 2 Problem 7

Tags: probability, combinatorics, problem-solving, word-problem

I wrote a combinatorial probability question, and I am not sure if my solution is correct. It is just a slight rewording of a problem from Sheldon Ross's A First Course in Probability 10th ed. Chapter 2 Problem 7. I would like to know your thoughts.

**Question:**

"Vince's carnival choo-choo train containing 16 people first stops at station 1 and stops last at station 5. After station 5, it must be completely empty. People can leave at any station but not board, and each person is equally likely to leave at any stop. Additionally, the passengers are leaving independent of each other. What is the probability that exactly half of the people have left by station 2?"

**My Solution**

First, we calculate the number of ways the event could take place.

Let $x_i$ be the amount of people who left at station $i$, where $i \in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.

Firstly, there are ${{16}\choose{8}}$ ways to choose the eight people that will have left after station two. We then consider a specific $(x_1,x_2)$. From the 8, there are ${{8}\choose{x_1}}$ for people to leave at station 1, and there are ${{8-x_1}\choose{x_2}}$ at station 2. Then, we sum through all possible $x_1$'s and $x_2$'s that satisfy $x_1+x_2=8$. Giving us:

$$\sum_{x_1+x_2=8}{{8}\choose{x_1}}{{8-x_1}\choose{x_2}}$$
Multiplying them together, we have:
$$
{{16}\choose{8}}\sum_{x_1+x_2=8}{{8}\choose{x_1}}{{8-x_1}\choose{x_2}}={{16}\choose{8}}\sum_{x_1+x_2=8}\frac{8!}{{x_1}!{x_2}!}={{16}\choose{8}}2^8
$$

Next, we compute the ways for the remaining 8 people to leave the last three stations. For some $(x_3,x_4,x_5)$, there are ${{8}\choose{x_3}}{{8-x_3}\choose{x_4}}{{8-x_3-x_4}\choose{x_5}}$ ways for the remaining people to leave within stations 3 to 5. Summing through all possible $x_3,x_4,$ and $x_5$ such that $x_3+x_4+x_5=8$, we have:

$$\sum_{x_3+x_4+x_5=8}{{8}\choose{x_3}}{{8-x_3}\choose{x_4}}{{8-x_3-x_4}\choose{x_5}}=\sum_{x_3+x_4+x_5=8}\frac{8!}{{x_3}!{x_4}!{x_5}!}=3^8$$

There are ${{16}\choose{8}}{2^8}{3^8}$ outcomes in the event.

Finally, we calculate the number of possible outcomes in the entire sample space.

Following the same argument as above, given a specific $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)$ there are ${{16}\choose{x_1}}{{16-x_1}\choose{x_2}}{{16-x_1-x_2}\choose{x_3}}{{16-x_1-x_2-x_3}\choose{x_4}}{{16-x_1-x_2-x_3-x_4}\choose{x_5}}$ ways for the 16 people to leave within stations 1 to 5.

Summing through all possible $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,$ and $x_5$ such that  $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=16$, we have:

$$\sum_{x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=16}{{16}\choose{x_1}}{{16-x_1}\choose{x_2}}{{16-x_1-x_2}\choose{x_3}}{{16-x_1-x_2-x_3}\choose{x_4}}{{16-x_1-x_2-x_3-x_4}\choose{x_5}}$$

$$=\sum_{x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=16}\frac{16!}{{x_1}!{x_2}!{x_3}!{x_4}!{x_5}!}=5^{16}$$

So the probability is:

**$$\frac{{{16}\choose{8}}{2^8}{3^8}}{5^{16}}\approx 0.1417$$**

**Edit:** I added necessary assumptions based on the comments

Comment: The problem is annoyingly vague...are we to assume that passengers are equally likely to get off at any stop? More seriously, I'd read the problem as requiring that *at least* $8$ people get off at one of the first two stops, not *exactly* $8$.

Comment: In any case, assuming a uniform distribution, there is a $\frac 25$ chance that a person gets off at one of the first two stops.  Thus the answer is $\sum_{k=8}^{16}\binom {16}k \times \left(\frac 25\right)^k\times \left(\frac 35\right)^{16-k}$ using my *at least* reading.  If you want the *exactly* reading, just take the term with $k=8$.

Comment: Sorry, the question is written like that because I based it off how it was written in the book. To answer your question, yes, passengers are equally likely to get off at any stop. I wrote the problem thinking of "exactly" 8. I will edit the question based on your comments! Thank you!

The assumption in your solution matches the assumptions for the problem, and I am happy to see that my answer matches yours (using the "exactly" reading). Though, I did not realize that it could be solved like that, I may have greatly overthought this question. 

Comment: Independence is a necessary assumption also.  If the $16$ were one big family group then the answer is $\frac 25$, since they either all get off early or they all get off later.

Comment: I see. I only finished the first two chapters of the book I mentioned  (which covers combinatorics and probability axioms). So, the word "independent" was not that familiar to me when I wrote the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

the problem needs clarification.  First of all, it seems we are to assume a uniform distribution and independence, which is far from obvious (in real life, people travel in groups and, of course, some stops will be more popular than others).

Secondly, I would read the problem as requiring that *at least* $8$ people leave at one of the first two stations, not *exactly* $8$.

In any case:

Assuming uniformity and independence, there is a $\frac 25$ chance that a given passenger gets off at one of the first two stops.  It follows that the probability that at least $8$ people do that is:

$$\sum_{k=8}^{16}\binom {16}k \times \left(\frac 25\right)^k\times \left(\frac 35\right)^{16-k}$$

If we want *exactly* $8$, then we just take the term corresponding to $k=8$, $$\binom {16}8 \times \left(\frac 25\right)^8\times \left(\frac 35\right)^{8}$$

which matches your result.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments!